# What extended ASCII encoding is this and how can I get ruby to understand it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, extended-ascii

The characters `0x91`, `0x92`, `0x93`, and `0x94` are supposed to represent what in Unicode are `U+2018`, `U+2019`, `U+201c`, and `U+201d`, or the "opening single quote", "closing single quote", "opening double quote", and "closing double quote". I thought that it was `ISO-8859-1` but when I try to process a file using `IO.read('file', :encoding=>'ISO-8859-1')` it still does not recognize these characters.

If it isn't `ISO-8859-1` then what is it? And if it is, why doesn't ruby recognize these characters?

UPDATE: Apparently this encoding is supposed to be Windows-1252. But ruby still does not recognize these characters when I do `IO.read('file', :encoding=>'Windows-1252')`.

UPDATE 2: Nevermind, `Windows-1252` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0x91 is the [Windows-1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) representation of Unicode's `\u2018` (AKA `‘`):

```
>> "\x91".force_encoding('windows-1251').encode('utf-8')
=> "‘"
```

Windows-1251 and Latin-1 (AKA ISO 8859-1) are not the same, try using `windows-1251` as the encoding:

```
IO.read('file', :encoding => 'windows-1251')
```

That will give you a string that knows it is Windows-1251. If you want UTF-8, then perhaps you want to specifying the [`:internal_encoding` and `:external_encoding`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-c-new):

```
IO.read('file', :external_encoding => 'windows-1251', :internal_encoding => 'utf-8')
```

Comment: @Matt: If you `s = IO.read(..., :encoding => 'windows-1251')` and then look at `s.encoding`, you'll see that it is windows-1251. See my update to get UTF-8 out.

Comment: It does that with any encoding even if the data is invalid.